# I want to link 2 models like a field abc linked to abcd model is in mymodel and a field in mod linked to mymodel is in abcd django

Tags: python, django

I want to link 2 models like a field abc linked to abcd model is in mymodel and a field in mod linked to mymodel is in abcd but shows mymodel isn't define because it is written after abcd model but if I replace the place of both model mymodel written above and abcd written after then mymodel shows that abcd isn't define...

Comment: Add quotes around your model name like `... ("Abcd", ...`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a string which includes the appname and model `'app_name:model_name'` like so:

```
abcd = models.ForeignKey('app_name:Abcd', ...)
```

Comment: TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type or tuple of types